# Considering Git, what are the Git references in ref/for/?

Tags: git

I understand the concepts behind `refs/heads/`, `refs/remotes/`, and `refs/tags/`. From time to time, I stumble upon Git references in `refs/for/`. What are these? Where do they point to? What does `for` stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not part of regular git, it's part of [gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/)

There's a good explanation of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461214/why-do-git-push-gerrit-headrefs-for-master-instead-of-git-push-origin-master)