# How to push the first commit into a new remote git project?

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

I have a new project on gerrit named my_project and I am its integrator.

I do the following:

```
git clone ssh://gerrit.local.server.com:29418/my_project
cd my_project
git remote add bla ssh://gerrit.local.server.com:29418/my_project
git fetch bla
echo 111 > try.txt
git commit -as
```

And all these tries fail with no permmision error (I am an integrator and I use with the right user, RSA key and email in all the configs files):

```
git push origin master
git push ssh://gerrit.local.server.com:29418/my_project refs/heads/* refs/tags/*
```

**What do I miss here?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461214/why-do-git-push-gerrit-headrefs-for-master-instead-of-git-push-origin-master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to bypass review?  If not, you need to push to `refs/for/master`, not `master`:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

If you are trying to bypass review, you need to make sure you have write permissions on `refs/heads/master`

Comment: what is the difference between `HEAD:refs/for/master` and `refs/heads/master`

Comment: `refs/for/master` is a Gerrit-specific trick.  `refs/heads/master` is the full git notation for the `master` branch.  When you specify a branch name, `refs/heads/` is prepended behind the scenes if you don't specify a ref space.  `refs/for/[blah]` is a namespace Gerrit uses to indicate 'create a code review for the [blah] branch.  Once the review is approved/submitted, it gets put on the `refs/heads/[blah]` branch.