# Why we use Git pull --rebase and not git pull in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit, rebase, git-pull

I am new in gerrit and i had a doubt that why we not use the simple pull like Git in gerrit and instead, we use git pull --rebase?

Secondly (different question), can you please state me why we need to give a special target reference while pushing the changes in gerrit?

Comment: What makes you think `--rebase` is a "special target reference"? Rebasing isn't about target references... it's about whether to merge the incoming changes with yours, or whether to reapply your changes on top of the incoming changes.

Comment: Do see the edited question

Comment: Only ask one question per post, please... now, do you understand what `git pull --rebase` does? (It's not like it's gerrit-specific...)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question: there is an excellent answer on stackoverflow already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10461674