# How to push for Gerrit review via Git Extension?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-extensions, git-review

Is there a way to push for gerrit review via Git-Extension ?

instead of using this command in gitbash

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/newFeature
```

Comment: You could at least use the script feature of GitExtensions (see in the settings) to run this command and even add it as an icon in the icon bar.

Comment: In my case, we use a python package called "git review" [link](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/git-review) . You can push for gerrit review with the command `git review <branch_name>`

Comment: You can [configure Git](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29585536/878514) so it remembers how to push changes to Gerrit.

Answer (score 2):

In push dialog add refs/for/ before the destination branch and it works.

see the image for an example:
[image: Example of usage]

It is not really the final solution but a workaround to use git extensions in gerrit.